# Plotting a graph with its vertices on a circle

Tags: graphs-and-networks

If have the following code.

```
AdjacencyGraph[Table[Boole[CoprimeQ[i - j, 8]], {j, 0, 7}, {i, 0, 7}]]
```

This generates a graph with 8 vertices. If the vertices are labeled 0, 1, ..., 7, where two vertices are adjacent whenever their difference is relatively prime to 8 (so 3 and 6 are adjacent since 6 - 3 =  3 is relatively prime to 8). I would like to have the graph drawn so that the vertices are in specific positions. Specifically, I would like to have the vertices 0, 1, ..., 7 evenly spaced around a circle in this order. In other words, this the graph should look like a regular octagon with additional edges inside. Is there a way to modify my code so that the vertices get drawn in this way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the option `GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"`:

```
k = 7;
AdjacencyGraph[Range[0, k], 
 Table[Boole[CoprimeQ[i - j, k + 1]], {j, 0, k}, {i, 0, k}], 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

You can also use [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) to get the same result:

```
RelationGraph[CoprimeQ[# - #2, k + 1] &, Range[0, k], 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium]
```

> same picture

Comment: Is it true?
`k = 7;
AdjacencyGraph[Range[0, k], 
 Table[Boole[CoprimeQ[i - j, k + 1]], {j, 0, k}, {i, 0, k}], 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium]`

Comment: @minhthien_2016, yes.